# How to select multiple files starting with same name in batch script?

Tags: windows

IF NOT EXIST "%INBOUND_FOLDER%\SYG_Req.csv"

(
        echo Random Text >>"%ARCHIVE_FOLDER%\nofile_SYG_Req_%NOW%.csv"
    )   ELSE 
    (
        Call core\TCC.bat "%SCRIPTS_FOLDER%\requisition-merge\Requisition_Import_cfg.xml" "%INBOUND_FOLDER%\SYG_Req.csv" "%ARCHIVE_FOLDER%\SYG_Req_result_%NOW%.csv"
    )

i have multiple files starting for SYG_Req in my inbound folder, i need to process them one by one ..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, read the [ask] page and update your question.